# Include all elements from a cell array into a for loop in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, cell

I have a cell array where the cells are something like this: [ 92x1 double] [215x1 double] [127x1 double] [120x1 double] [ 89x1 double] ....and so on(1000 odd cells). I want to be able to extract the first n and last n elements in each of those arrays and get their means. I want all of that in one loop. I tried using a 'for' loop for this but it only gets the required elements from either the first or the last cell array and not all the cells. 
Im quite new to this and any help would be great! Thanks

```
for i=1:nfiles,
a{i} = diff(w{i}(:,2))./diff(w{i}(:,1));

for k=1:numel(a{i}),
    begin= a{i}(1:5),
e_elements = a{i}(end-4:end),
end 
end
```

Comment: I think the first `for` loop should be ended on line 3.
The index in the second `for` loop is `k`, so inside the loop it should be `a{k}`
Also, you don't need to use these commas but semicolon instead.

Comment: 1. You overwrite your variable on each loops. 2. Your second loop is useless. 3. You don't need to create 2 variables you can do something like `nval[i,:] = a{i}([1:5,end-5:end])`.